# A connection between a sequence from the Collatz conjecture and a sequence of densities from $\zeta(k)-1$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, riemann-zeta

Just for grins, I created lists of first-entries of finite sequences of rank $r$ for the Syracuse problem (Collatz conjecture using only odd numbers) and found these sequences on OEIS. My sequences, constructed by the expression on RHS below, are odd numbers only and are the same as the odd numbers in each $\zeta(k)-1$ sequence.

With $k=2,$ [A143028](http://oeis.org/A143028)
With $k=3,$ [A143029](http://oeis.org/A143029)

With $k=4,$ [A143030](http://oeis.org/A143030) (odd numbers only) $\cong$ With $r=k-1, \{(2 c-1) 2^r-1\}_{c=1}^{8}$
$\{ 7, 23, 39, 50, 55, 71, 87, 103, 104, 119\}$ (odd numbers only) $\cong$
$ \{ 7, 23, 39, { }\uparrow{ }, 55, 71, 87, 103,{ }{ }{ }\uparrow{ }{ }{ }, 119\}$
$\uparrow$ points to an interstitial even number.

With $k=5,$ [A143031](http://oeis.org/A143031)
With $k=6,$ [A143032](http://oeis.org/A143032)
With $k=7,$ [A143033](http://oeis.org/A143033)
With $k=8,$ [A143034](http://oeis.org/A143034)
With $k=9,$ [A143035](http://oeis.org/A143035)
With $k=10,$ [A143036](http://oeis.org/A143036)

These OEIS sequences are from:
William J. Keith [Sequences of density zeta(k) - 1](http://arxiv.org/abs/0905.3765v2)

Would this indicate a connection between the Collatz conjecture and densities in the $\zeta(k)-1$ sequence?

**Edit** The connection is coincidental. However, these sequences can be produced by a simple sieving method:

Start with a list of all odd numbers.
Remove every other number and save to a list. This will be the $\zeta(k)-1$ odd numbers. Repeat this step for each successive $k$.

The count of odd numbers is halved at each step.

Comment: According to my calculations, the syracuse orbit of 39 has 11 terms (not 4)